# SQL - Get number of Product in an order and total value

Tags: sql

Current Database:

tbl_Order:

```
ID.........UserName........date
1..........john............march 30 2017
2..........mike............march 31 2017
```

tbl_Products_In_Order

```
Order_ID.........Qty_Purchased........UnitPrice........TotalPrice
1...............2.....................1.00.............2.00
1...............3.....................2.00.............6.00
2...............1.....................8.00.............8.00
```

i need the output to be:

```
Order_ID...UserName...date............Number_Of_Products.........Total_Qty_All
1..........John.......march 30 2017...2..........................5
2..........mike.......march 31 2017...1..........................1
```

Can someone help me create the SQL query?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `SUM()`, `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PostgreSQL solution (but using just basic stuff, so should be same or very similar in most SQL dialects):

```
SELECT
  Order_ID,
  UserName,
  date,
  count(Order_ID) AS Number_Of_Products,
  sum(Qty_Purchased) AS Total_Qty_All
FROM
  tbl_Products_In_Order AS pio
  INNER JOIN tbl_Order AS o ON pio.Order_ID = o.ID
GROUP BY Order_ID, UserName, date
ORDER BY Order_ID
```

Comment: also need to include "UserName" and "date" from tbl_Order

Comment: Lol ok, but that wasn't in the original version of your question...

Comment: lol. Yes I just realized that I didn't have it there

Comment: Uh, why the downvote? | Ok so I changed it to what you wanted @John-AJ. But this is really basic stuff, you should learn this yourself if you need to work with SQL.

Comment: it wasn't me who did the downvote,, ill try that query. thanks a lot!